# Elements getting overlapped in select drop down material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, formsy-material-ui

I am new to react and am using the select button of material-ui. It adds a highlight text of whatever we give and it should go away once the element is selected.

[image]

However on the selection of an option the two texts get blurred like this:

[image]

Here is the code for the same:

```
<Grid item xs={6}>
                <FormControl id="Process" style={{ width: "78%" }} size="small">
                  <InputLabel
                    htmlFor="Process"
                    id="Process"
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: 10,
                      top: "50%",
                      transform: "translate(0,-50%"
                    }}
                  >
                    Process
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="Process"
                    name="Process"
                    id="Process"
                    onChange={() => this.setState({ addModalShow: true })}
                    defaultValue={values.Process}
                    variant="outlined"
                    inputProps={{
                      id: "Process"
                    }}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value="1">Implemented</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="2">Implementation in Progress</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="3">Not Implemented</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <Button
                  variant="outlined"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={() => this.setState({ addModalShow: true })}
                  size="small"
                  style={styles.button2}
                >
                  +
                </Button>
                <label
                  id="process"
                  style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}
                >
                  Process cannot be blank
                </label>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Could anyone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Where is the `values` variable? Is it assigned via `useState()`?

Comment: no values variable is not assigned

Comment: I'm trying to understand what `defaultValue={values.Process}` results in.

Comment: even if you remove that the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, your problem is connected to the `style` you applied on `InputLabel`. In standard version, `InputLabel` does not disappears when you select a value on `Select` component. Will be just moved on top of the `Select` element.

If you made a style customization on `InputLabel`, the label will be not moved on top and you will see the two texts blurred. So you have 2 choices:

1. Remove style customization, I mean remove this css:

   ```
   style={{
      marginLeft: 10,
      top: "50%",
      transform: "translate(0,-50%"
   }}
   ```
2. put a condition to `InputLabel` content. Something like:

   ```
   {values.Process === "" && "Process"}
   ```

In this way, `Process` label will be visible only if you haven't selected nothing on `Select` component.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-forked-3ryq4?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: Hi when I put {values.Process === "" && "Process"}, the entire Process tag goes away, also If I remove the style the  process does not line up correctly

Comment: @sandeeppradhan the condition I suggested depends on your logic. What is the default value for `values.Process` in your code? In my example is "".

Comment: The default value that it should show is process. Do you mean that? I put it there to keep the value there when i Come back from the next page. We can also remove that if you want. What should I do?

Comment: @sandeeppradhan look my example. the initial value for `values.Process` is "" (`const [values, setValues] = useState({ Process: "" });`). So you condition should be `{values.Process === <yourInitialValue> && "Process"}`

Comment: How are you showing Process initially and then it dissapears when you select something.That is what I want to do

Comment: Can you share how to do that in a class component?

Comment: @sandeeppradhan I have updated my codesandbox using class component https://codesandbox.io/s/override-select-component-material-ui-forked-3ryq4?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @sandeeppradhan look better my example. Have you noted that when I call `onChange` I set the `Process` value? Have you noted that `MenuItem` value prop is changed? Let me see your code. Make a codesandbox with your code (even if it doesn't work) and I will adjust it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-surf-8cf2p?file=/src/App.js  This is the link to the sand box

Comment: @sandeeppradhan https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-haibt-8pq29?file=/src/App.js I have added a bool variable on state (`ProcessSelected`), then on Select change I setted the bool value to `true` and I added a new condition in `InputLabel`. Now should work :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lot for your help Giovanni, We have been going at it what for 4 hours now Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem @sandeeppradhan :)